# What's the best affordable high-speed SSD Hard drive if I want to upgrade the laptop?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, sata, hardware-rec

What's the best affordable high-speed SSD Hard drive if I want to upgrade the laptop?

I am using a laptop (Model: Lenovo Ideapad 700-151SK) and I did replace the original hard drive with Western Digital 2TB SATA 6Gb/s (WD20SPZX)and bought it for about ~ $75 it should be 6Gb/s as it's advertised but I think it has very slow performance, not sure which caused the issue and I use Windows 10 Operating system which takes about 200GB of the storage with all the apps and data.

I found this hard drive online:
SanDisk SSD PLUS 2TB Internal SSD - SATA III 6 Gb/s, 2.5"/7mm, Up to 545 MB/s - SDSSDA-2T00-G26
and cost about $200 to replace the hard drive, would you recommend me to switch to it, and will it makes a better performance than Western Digital SATA?

Comment: I have Samsung SSD drives in my laptop (1 drive) and my desktop (2 drives). Reliability has been excellent and the 1 TB laptop drive (the smallest I have) is good for 600 TBW. It is at 32 TBW after 4 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to unpack here.

You were mislead about the speed of your WD hard drive.  A hard drive is a spinning disk, so the speeds top out at way less then 200 megabytes/second on top of the line drives. - although it has an interface speed of 6Gb/s this is not indiative of its performance - a typical mid-range 2.5" hard drive - which yours is, will probably get transfer **speeds of up to 100 Megabytes per second**.  Arguably more important is the IOPS.   This is the time from requesting data until the time the server has it.  Because hard drives are spinning disk, the IOPS are very slow.

A typical SATA SSD will have a typical performance of 400-550 Megabytes per second - however it is in actuality much faster then a hard drive - not because of the max speed, but because the IOPS is orders of magnitude faster, because there is no waiting for the platter to spin to the correct position.  **This means that even a slow SSD will outperform a fast hard drive by 10x + in reality**

The fastest SSD's change, but this is largely irrelevant here because the bottleneck is the SATA interface.  Any decent SATA SSD should more-or-less max out the 6Gigabit/second bus (its gigabit, not gigabyte, so a bit more then 500 megabyte/second).  The Samsung 870 Evo drive has speeds of 530-560 MBps - which is about as good as you can get, and this is a reasonably reputed drive from a reputed manufacturer.    The Crucial MX500 series is a close second.     The SANDISK you mention above should also be Ok.

Comment: Thanks a lot @davidgo